# Calculate AGE from date of birth in REDSHIFT

Tags: sql, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I tried the below but none of them work in redshift

```
datediff(current_date, str_to_date(dob, '%d,-%m-%Y'))/365 as age_today 
year(current_date)-year(dob) as age_in_years
```

The dob is in format 1955-03-20 00:00:00.0

Comment: What do you mean by "none of them work"? Do they give an error, or just return the wrong result?

Answer (score 0):

Please mention `datepart` in `datediff()` function:

```
datediff(day, dob ,current_date)/365 as age_today
```

For further read:
[Redshift datediff function documentation.](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html)

Comment: Invalid operation: function str_to_date(timestamp without time zone, "unknown") does not exist;

Comment: I just copied that part from your question. Would you please try the query without using str_to_date()

Comment: And how to check age for a specific date, I want to know as of 02/15/2022 what was the age of user?

Comment: datediff(day, dob ,'02/15/2022')/365 as age_at_given_day

Comment: If I divide by 365 it will not be accurate for some cases considering leap year, is there any alternative to not utilize this.

Comment: The below works accurately: (considering leap years as well)
((DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.dob, '02/15/2022') - 
          CASE 
            WHEN '02/15/2022' < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.dob,'02/15/2022'), a.dob) 
          THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
            END )) AS age

Answer (score 0):

I haven't tested this, but how about:

```
datediff(year, dob, current_date + interval '1 year' - interval '1 day') as age
```

It calculates the difference in years between the birth date and the date in one year (minus one day) to account for partial years. It would handle leap years.

Comment: The age is not accurate for majority of the cases.

Comment: In which cases is it not accurate? Did you manage to fix it?

Comment: This one works (I was look age as of 02/15/2022, but you can update accordingly):
((DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.dob, '02/15/2022') - 
          CASE 
            WHEN '02/15/2022' < DATEADD(YEAR, DATEDIFF(YEAR, a.dob,'02/15/2022'), a.dob) 
          THEN 1 
            ELSE 0
            END )) AS age

Answer (score 0):

For exact age in year you can use

```
case
  when ( add_months(current_date , date_diff('year', dob, current_date ) * (-12) ) ) < dob
  then date_diff('year', dob, current_date ) - 1
  else date_diff('year', dob, current_date )
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I would go with below code, where we take calendar year difference and reduce it by one if we still before birthday in current year.
It is easier to understand vs solution with moving birthday to current year and then compere. When condition if not meet on month comparison DBMS engine should not check days condition (so maybe is even faster in execution)

```
date_diff('year', birthdate, current_date)
-   case 
        -- if month is before or same and day if before today reduce age by one year
        when date_part(month, current_date) <= date_part(month, birthdate) 
        then 1
 
        when date_part(month, current_date) = date_part(month, birthdate)
             and date_part(day, current_date) < date_part(day, birthdate)
        then 1

        else 0 end
```

Comment: the `<=` should be `=`, the month and day case will never be evaluated because the `=` case is captured in the condition before it.